# c# / Adding selected combobox item to listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, combobox, listbox

I need to create a small application in Visual Studio using a Windows Form Application that will list the selected items from multiple comboboxes inside a listbox, and then add the total price of each selection and put in a textbox.  The issue is that the items aren't being added to the list upon selection. I had a similar issue with a previous app and realized I was using `SelectedIndex` rather than `SelectedIndexChanged` in the method declaration. That isn't the case this time. I'm still pretty new to C#, so I apologize for any sloppy code.

`lbDishes` is the design name for the listbox and `txtTotal` is the textbox for Total price to be displayed.

```
namespace Exercise_15._9
{
public partial class ResBillCalc : Form
{
    public ResBillCalc()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Method to handle the SelectedIndexChanged event of cbBeverage       

    private void cbBeverage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,
        EventArgs e)
    {
        // add selected item to ListBox
        lbDishes.Items.Add(cbBeverage.Text);

        //Switch to appropriate choice to get subtotal price
        switch (cbBeverage.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                txtTotal.Text =
                    Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text) + 1.95);
                break;

            case 1:
                txtTotal.Text =
                    Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text) + 1.50);
                break;

            case 2:
                txtTotal.Text =
                    Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text) + 1.25);
                break;

            case 3:
                txtTotal.Text =
                    Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text) + 2.95);
                break;

            case 4:
                txtTotal.Text =
                    Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text) + 2.50);
                break;

            case 5:
                txtTotal.Text =
                    Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text) + 1.50);
                break;
        }
    }

    // Method to handle SelectedIndexChanged event of cbAppetizer
    private void cbAppetizer_SelectedIndexChanged (object sender,
        EventArgs e)
    {
        // add selected item to ListBox
        lbDishes.Items.Add(cbAppetizer.Text);

        //Switch to appropriate choice to get subtotal
        switch (cbAppetizer.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                txtTotal.Text =
                    Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text) + 5.95);
                break;

            case 1:
                txtTotal.Text =
                    Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text) + 6.95);
                break;

            case 2:
                txtTotal.Text =
                    Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text) + 8.95);
                break;

            case 3:
                txtTotal.Text =
                    Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text) + 8.95);
                break;

            case 4:
                txtTotal.Text =
                    Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text) + 10.95);
                break;

            case 5:
                txtTotal.Text =
                    Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text) + 12.95);
                break;

            case 6:
                txtTotal.Text =
                    Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text) + 6.95);
                break;
        }
    }

    // Method to handle SelectedIndexChanged event of cbMainCourse
    private void cbMainCourse_SelectedIndexChanged (object sender,
        EventArgs e)
    {
        lbDishes.Items.Add(cbMainCourse.Text);

        //Switch to appropriate choice to get subtotal
        switch (cbMainCourse.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                txtTotal.Text =
                    Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text) + 13.95);
                break;

            case 1:
                txtTotal.Text =
                    Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text) + 13.95);
                break;

            case 2:
                txtTotal.Text =
                    Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text) + 11.95);
                break;

            case 3:
                txtTotal.Text =
                    Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text) + 19.95);
                break;

            case 4:
                txtTotal.Text =
                    Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text) + 20.95);
                break;

            case 5:
                txtTotal.Text =
                    Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text) + 18.95);
                break;

            case 6:
                txtTotal.Text =
                    Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text) + 13.95);
                break;

            case 7:
                txtTotal.Text =
                    Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text) + 14.95);
                break;

            case 8:
                txtTotal.Text =
                    Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text) + 15.95);
                break;
        }
    }

    // Method to handle SelectedIndexChange event of cbDessert
    private void cbDessert_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,
        EventArgs e)
    {
        // Add selected text to ListBox
        lbDishes.Items.Add(cbDessert.Text);

        // Switch to choice to get subtotal
        switch (cbDessert.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                txtTotal.Text =
                    Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text) + 5.95);
                break;

            case 1:
                txtTotal.Text =
                    Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text) + 3.95);
                break;

            case 2:
                txtTotal.Text =
                    Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text) + 5.95);
                break;

            case 3:
                txtTotal.Text =
                    Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text) + 4.95);
                break;

            case 4:
                txtTotal.Text =
                    Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text) + 5.95);
                break;
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: try `lbDishes.Items.Add(cbAppetizer.SelectedItem.ToString());`

Comment: No luck. I've tried `cbAppetizer.SelectedText` as well

Comment: the code to add the items to the listbox works just fine. Did you check whether the name of the `ListBox` is correct, also check the `font colour` of the `ListBox`, may be you just don't see it. You should set a break point in one of the `SelectedIndexChanged` events and look in the debugger, whether an item has been added

Comment: So I found the issue was that the methods weren't registering after setting a break point and checking the Designer.cs

Comment: did you write the code for the `private void cbBeverage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,
        EventArgs e)` by hand? next time you can just double click it in the property / event box of the control in the designer

Comment: That was exactly the issue. I was aware of the ability to double click items to add events but I'm just used to writing everything by hand